# textmate no longer removing blank lines

Tags: textmate

Something very strange has happened to my textmate installation.

It is no longer removing blank lines in any document.   If I press the delete key in any document where a blank line is, it just moves the cursor up a line without actually removing the blank line.

Has anyone experienced this weird behaviour and does anyone know how to stop it.  This has only just started happening after months of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I haven't seen this behavior, I have in other discussions on SO seen odd problems with TextMate having been solved with a re-installation.

Answer (score 2):

Go into Edit->Mode->Overwrite Mode and change it back. Reinstall will help but only if you wipe out your user settings.